# Solving 4th order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is rather a general mathematical question, but I would be very thankful, if you could help me anyway:

I want to solve the following 4th order ODE

$\frac{\text{d}^4 w}{\text{d}x^4}+ 4b^4 w == 0$

Solving this with Mathematica gives me:

$c_1 e^{(-1+i) b x}+c_2 e^{(-1-i) b x}+c_3 e^{(1-i) b x}+c_4 e^{(1+i) b x} \, ,$

and by using the euler identity, it can be rewritten with $c_3 = c_4 = 0$ as:

$e^{-b x} \left\{ c_1 \left[cos(bx) + i\cdot sin(bx) \right] + c_2  \left[cos(bx) - i\cdot sin(bx) \right] \right\} \, .$

However, in literature I find the result:

$e^{-b x} \left[c_1 cos(bx) +c_2  sin(bx) \right]$

Could anyone tell me, why this is the same? 
What might be relevant: It might be relevant that this is a structural mechanics problem, where w is a deflection, which should have a real value.
Free hugs to everyone, independently if (s)he solves the problem or not.

Comment: Enlightenment! Thanks a lot! I knew that I was missing an easy step! Obviously mathematica doesn't do the substitution on its own. 
If you post it as an answer I can mark it as solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.